# How can I tell if these pipes are gas pipes or water pipes?

Tags: water, gas

I have recently bought a property and am re-doing the kitchen. Whilst stripping the old kitchen the builder has come accross some pipes which I ideally want removed. Have attached images of the pipes. These pipes seem to end up below the staircase and are capped over there. So they dont seem to be going anywhere further. Can someone let me know if these are water or gas pipes and if it safe to tamper with them i.e. cut and cap them at the floor level itself.![image]

enter image description here

[image]

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [How can I tell if these pipes are gas lines or water lines?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/13126/33)

Comment: Those might have been for radiant heat. How old is the building? Do you know if it ever have radiators?

Comment: While the question is essentially a duplicate, the photos justify this being a more valuable and answerable question.

Comment: Those are most likely hot water heat supply and return pipes. It wouldn't make sense to run two parallel gas lines unless this is a multi family with separate meters. In any case, I see a union on one of the pipes. It's not recommended to have those inside the walls, so that's another reason to cap or remove the pipes

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys. I understand that a similar question has been asked before but after having a look at my pipes I couldnt say for sure if they are gas or water but what Vitality said makes sense.